# Is there a general USB 3.0 support in OpenWrt?

Tags: kernel, usb, openwrt

the only [information](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/usb.essentials#modules_for_usb_30) i found about this topic is outdated since 2011/02: *it says there is no support for devices with usb 3.0 "so far"*!

according to the [german wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_%28Kernel%29#Versionsgeschichte_ab_Version_2.6) since version 2.6.30 the linux kernel supports usb 3.0; so i assume that [since OpenWrt Backfire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenWrt#Releases) usb 3.0 should be supported...

---

for example the [posted `dmesg` of this router](https://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/d-link/dir-860l#openwrt_dmesg_with_relevant_backports_up_to_r47238) includes some lines for a *xHCI Host Controller*, so maybe i'm right... but im not sure because of included *"backports up to r47238"* and i'm not so familiar with kernel-development/-commands.
...it is clear that it may depend on the device/hardware/controller but i'm talking about the general support!

---

has anyone better sources to clarify the usb support of OpenWrt? ...or at least personal experience in using OpenWrt with a usb 3.0 device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use LEDE now instead of OpenWRT, but both do support USB 3.0 (assuming your router also supports it).

What I'm curious about is whether it supports USB hubs. My router has 2 USB ports, but only one is 3.0.

Comment: well, i would assume if usb x.y is supported, also usb hubs with usb x.y are supported... but i may be wrong, i'm not so good at hardware-related questions. **:-/** -- for sure rates will be split!